# Spelling errors at the (CDN) style sheets

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When I analysed the CSS style sheets of some SE websites, I ran across some typos.

- [Stack Overflow](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=0572493b9894) (also meta):

  ```
  .suggested-edit .body-diffs .full-html-diff .gutter     /* Selector */
      max-width:10x;                                      /* Property */
                  ^ Replace `x` with `px`
  ```
- [TeX](http://cdn.sstatic.net/tex/all.css?v=76cdfa935829)

  ```
  .answered-accepted .mini-counts AND .answered-accepted strong
      borer-bottom:1px solid #f2fcea;
         ^ Replace `borer-bottom` with `border-bottom`
  ```

I encountered these errors when I parsed the CSS using [code beautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/), to check the possibility of overriding the TeX' stylesheet using [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), to be more comfortable. If you find other errors in other SE sites, feel free to post them as an answer.

PS. Do not add an answer about [`\9`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/804060/938089), valid CSS3 or vendor-specific properties, as the parser is like a human: Capable of committing mistakes.

Comment: [Jigsaw W3C CSS validator results for Stack Overflow's stylesheet](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.sstatic.net%2Fstackoverflow%2Fall.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=true&lang=en), CSS3 mode and vendor extensions only triggering warnings - guess how many errors left are the aforementioned hacks...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Are these bugs going to be fixed? Or is it too difficult to update the files?

Comment: Not a clue... I'm not one of the developers :| I suppose you could drop a bounty to get some attention from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stack Overflow stylesheet no longer has that typo, but I fixed up the TeX ones (and Wordpress).

Going live in the next build.

Comment: why the rush, it's not even three years since the report... (but +1)

Comment: @CareBear Good point. We're really running the risk that folks will start to expect timely bug fixes around here.